The SAGA "Real surface area" tool outputs a raster with impossible band values
I want to know the real surface area of my polygon in a mountainous region.
I use these steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzqwEs9OkJ4
I downloaded the DEM from https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/ - ASTER Global Digital Elevation Model V003, specific ID: ASTGTMV003_N13E039. The resolution is 30m. Highest point is 3004m, lowest 701m.

I use QGIS version 3.32.3-Lima.

When I run the SAGA real surface area tool, it gives me a raster with a band just like the video shows. However, a polygon with an area of 615ha calculated with zonal statistics returns only an area of 32ha.

As I check the value of the bands, it goes from 0 to 0.025.

I measure everything in hectares (so in project settings and in the settings of real surface area tool). The pixels however are 30mX30m, so the surface area of 1 pixel should at least be 0.09ha. Which is clearly not the case. When I adjust the measurement units (to square miles, to square meters, ... ), the values do not change (it goes from 0 to 0.025).
Is this possible to solve?

https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/790705/thread/db51d896/ I guess that you must reproject your dem into some projected coordinate system first.

Great! That was indeed the solution, thank you!
